# Can java 8 streams fan out

Tags: java-stream

I would like to build a stream from a set of files so the the last stream in the chain provides individual lines.

I assume I can use Files.find to get a stream of Paths and then Files.lines to build a stream of lines for each file, but how do I combine them into a single stream.

I'm new to streams so the question might be based on a misconception.

Comment: It's actually a bit hard to follow you here... can you provide an example? Not necessarily actually code, but *something* the could exemplify your problem.

Comment: `flatMap` is used to merge a stream of streams.

Comment: I want a stream where the input is a set of files or a file pattern or something like that and the output is each line in these files. The implementation should never read more than one line at a time, never the whole file.

@4castle This seems to be the answer.

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind here is: how do you want to close each individual file after you read all its lines if you use a stream?

Comment: @JDC If Files.lines is the final stream in the pipeline, then it will close the file after it has been through all the lines.